Serilog Db Logging issue with middleware ASP.NET Core Web API
namespace FraudPortalService.Shared.Logging
{
    public class FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware1
    {
       private readonly ILogger<FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware> _logger;
       
        private readonly Stopwatch _watch = new Stopwatch();
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
        private static bool _allowReqRespLog;
        internal ServiceLogDTO log { get; set; }

        public static LoggerConfiguration ConfigLog(ref LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
            {
                AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
                {
                    new() { DataType = SqlDbType.Xml, ColumnName = "requestXml" },
                    new() { DataType = SqlDbType.Xml, ColumnName = "responseXml" },
                    new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "correlationId" },
                    new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "messageId" },

                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "methodType" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "url" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "header" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "request" },

                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "response" },

                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.SmallInt, ColumnName = "statusCode" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "appCode" },

                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "errMessage" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "stackTrace" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.SmallInt, ColumnName = "serverVersion" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "userId" },

                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "clientIp" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.DateTime, ColumnName = "timestamp1" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.Decimal, ColumnName = "duration" },
                        new() { DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, ColumnName = "applCode" },

                    }
            };
            columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
            columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
            columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Message);
            columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Exception);
            columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Level);

            loggerConfiguration
               .AuditTo.Logger(l =>
                    l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
                        //Add logging catagory
                        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e =>
                        Matching.FromSource("FraudPortalService.BusinessLayer.RiskCenterService").Invoke(e) ||
                                                     Matching.FromSource("FraudPortalService.Util.FraudPortalServiceReqRespTraceMiddleware").Invoke(e))
                        .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: config.GetConnectionString("Fraudportal"),
                            sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "LogToDBTest1", AutoCreateSqlTable = true },
                            columnOptions: columnOptions));
            return loggerConfiguration;
        }

        public FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware1(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration config,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            this._next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware>();
            _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
            _allowReqRespLog = bool.TryParse(config["AppSettings:EnableDBLogSensitiveData"], out var debugenabled) && debugenabled;
        }
       
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            _watch.Restart();
           
            string response = "";
            var isSwaggerorLogViewer = context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("swagger") || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("LogViewer")
                                                                                      || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("HealthCheck") ||
                                                                                      context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".ico")
                                                                                      || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".js") ||
        
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            DateTime reqTs = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                if (!isSwaggerorLogViewer)
                {
                    log = new ServiceLogDTO();

                    await LogRequest(context);
                    await LogResponse(context);
                    
                    WriteServiceLogs(log);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                watch.Stop();
            }
        }

        private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Request.EnableBuffering();

                await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);

                log.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                log.Url = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.Path}{context.Request.QueryString}";
                log.ClientIP = $"{context.Request.Host.Host}";
                log.MethodName = $"{context.Request.Method}";
                log.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get.ToString() || (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.ToString() && context.Request.Headers.ContentLength == 0))
                {
                    var queryParameters = context.Request.Query.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => string.Join(";", kv.Value), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); ;
                    result = FromDictionaryToJson(queryParameters);
                    log.Request = result;
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Request = context.Request.QueryString.Value.ToString();
                }

                // Environment.MachineName;
                log.UserId = context.User.Identity.Name;
                //httpRequestMessage.GetHeader(Util.Constants.Constant.CustomHeader.UserId);
                log.ServiceVersion = ConfigHelper.GetValue(Util.Constants.Constant.ApplicationSettings.ServiceVersion);
                log.StatusCode = (int)context.Response.StatusCode;
                // log.Request = FormatRequest(context.Request);
                log.Header = headers;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_logger.LogError(ex, "request/response logging exception");
                throw;
            }

            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }

        private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {
                await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;
                await _next(context);
                context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);

                log.StatusCode = (int)context.Response.StatusCode;
                log.Response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
                _watch.Stop();

                // log.ExecutionDuration = Convert.ToDecimal(_watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
                // await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_logger.LogError(ex, "request/response logging exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
            }

            //context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            //await _next(context);

            //log.StatusCode = (int)context.Response.StatusCode;
            //log.Response = await FormatResponse(context.Response);
            //_watch.Stop();
            //log.ExecutionDuration = Convert.ToDecimal(_watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            //await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }

        private void WriteServiceLogs(ServiceLogDTO serviceLog)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                // WebUtility.HtmlEncode(TraceLogEntity.LogTemplate),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ApplicationCode),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ClientIP),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.StatusCode.ToString()),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Header),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.CorrelationId),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ErrorMessage),
                WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Url),

            //WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.JsonRequest),                    
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Response),
            //log.JsonRequest,
            //log.JsonResponse,
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ExecutionDuration.ToString()),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Request),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Response),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ErrorMessage),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.StatusCode.ToString()),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.Header),
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.MessageId));
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.MethodName);
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.ServiceVersion);
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.StackTrace);
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.TimeStamp);
            WebUtility.HtmlEncode(serviceLog.UserId);
        }

        private async Task<string> FormatResponse(HttpResponse response)
        {
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var text = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return $"{text}";
        }

        //private void LogRequest(HttpRequest request)
        //{
        //    request.EnableRewind();
        //    using (var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
        //    {
        //        request.Body.CopyTo(requestStream);
        //        reques
        //        _logger.LogInformation($"Http Request Information:{Environment.NewLine}" +
        //                               $"Schema:{request.Scheme} " +
        //                               $"Host: {request.Host} " +
        //                               $"Path: {request.Path} " +
        //                               $"QueryString: {request.QueryString} " +
        //                               $"Request Body: {ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}");
        //    }
        //}
        //private static ServiceLogDTO CreateRequestLogObject(HttpRequestMessage httpRequest)
        //{
        //    var serviceLog = new ServiceLogDTO
        //    {
        //        //ClientIP = Extension.GetClientIp(httpRequest),
        //        ApplicationCode = httpRequest.GetHeader(Util.Constants.Constant.CustomHeader.ApplicationCode),
        //        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        //        CorrelationId = httpRequest.GetHeader(Util.Constants.Constant.CustomHeader.CorrelationId) ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        //        Header = httpRequest.Headers.ToString(),
        //        MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        //        MethodName = "",//Need to figure this out
        //        MethodType = httpRequest.Method.Method,
        //        Request = httpRequest.GetQueryStrings(),
        //        Url = httpRequest.RequestUri.AbsolutePath,
        //        UserId = httpRequest.GetHeader(Util.Constants.Constant.CustomHeader.UserId),
        //        ServiceVersion = ConfigHelper.GetValue(Util.Constants.Constant.ApplicationSettings.ServiceVersion),

        //    };
        //    return serviceLog;
        //}
        //private ServiceLogDTO CreateResponseLogObject(ServiceLogDTO serviceLog, HttpResponseMessage httpResponse)
        //{
        //    if (serviceLog == null)
        //    {
        //        return null;
        //    }

        //    serviceLog.StatusCode = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
        //    serviceLog.Response = httpResponse.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //    _watch.Stop();
        //    serviceLog.ExecutionDuration = Convert.ToDecimal(_watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        //    return serviceLog;
        //}

        public static string FromDictionaryToJson( Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            var kvs = dictionary.Select(kvp => $"\"{kvp.Key}\":\"{kvp.Value}\"");
            return string.Concat("{", string.Join(",", kvs), "}");
        }

        public static string FormatHeaders(IHeaderDictionary headers)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var (key, value) in headers)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine($"- {key}: {value}");
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public static string FormatHeaders(HttpRequestHeaders headers)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in headers)
            {
                var val = (item.Value == null) ? "" : (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(string[])) ? item.Value.First() : item.Value.ToString();
                stringBuilder.AppendLine($"- {item.Key}: {val}");
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
        {
            const HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                exceptionMessage = new
                {
                    errorType = "NA",
                    errorMessage = "Internal Server Error Occurred."

                }
            });

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;

            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }

        private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
        {
            const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;

            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk,
                    0,
                    readChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }

        //public static void ProcessOutboundResponse(ILogger logger, string logcategory, HttpContext? context,
        //    HttpResponseMessage response, HttpRequestMessage request, Exception? ex = null)
        //{
        //    var reqStr = request.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()?.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //    TraceLogEntity log = new TraceLogEntity(
        //        servername: Environment.MachineName,
        //        reqTimeStamp: request.Properties["BeginInvoke"] != null
        //            ? ((DateTime)request.Properties["BeginInvoke"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
        //            : string.Empty,
        //        logCategory: logcategory,
        //        inboundTraceId: context?.Request?.Headers["x-client-traceid"],
        //        header: FormatHeaders(request.Headers),
        //        httpMethod: request.Method.ToString(),
        //        url: request.RequestUri.ToString(),
        //        jsonRequest: _allowReqRespLog ? (reqStr == "null" ? null : reqStr) : string.Empty,
        //        jsonResponse: _allowReqRespLog ? response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()?.Result : string.Empty,
        //        executionDuration: $"{DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)request.Properties["BeginInvoke"]).TotalSeconds:F2}",
        //        isSuccess: ex == null ? true : false,
        //        inboundTraffic: false,
        //        errorMessage: null,
        //        exception: ex?.ToString(),
        //        traceIdentifier: context?.TraceIdentifier);
        //    logger.LogDebug(
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(TraceLogEntity.LogTemplate),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ReqTimeStamp),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.LogCategory),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.InboundTraceId),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Header),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.HttpMethod),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Url),
        //        //WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.JsonRequest),
        //        //WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.JsonResponse),
        //        log.JsonRequest,
        //        log.JsonResponse,
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ExecutionDuration),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.IsSuccess ? "true" : "false"),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.InboundTraffic ? "true" : "false"),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ErrorMessage),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Exception),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.TraceIdentifier),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ServerName));
        //}

        //public static void LogInternalMethodAcaps(ILogger logger, string logcategory, HttpContext context,
        //    DateTime startTm, string url, string reqStr, string respStr, Exception? ex = null)
        //{
        //    TraceLogEntity log = new TraceLogEntity(
        //        servername: Environment.MachineName,
        //        reqTimeStamp: startTm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        //        logCategory: logcategory,
        //        inboundTraceId: context?.Request?.Headers["x-client-traceid"],
        //        header: "",
        //        httpMethod: "POST",
        //        url: url,
        //        jsonRequest: reqStr == "null" ? null : reqStr,
        //        jsonResponse: respStr,
        //        executionDuration: $"{DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTm).TotalSeconds:F2}",
        //        isSuccess: ex == null ? true : false,
        //        inboundTraffic: false,
        //        errorMessage: ex?.Message,
        //        exception: ex?.ToString(),
        //        traceIdentifier: context?.TraceIdentifier);
        //    logger.LogDebug(
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(TraceLogEntity.LogTemplate),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ReqTimeStamp),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.LogCategory),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.InboundTraceId),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Header),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.HttpMethod),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Url),
        //        //WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.JsonRequest),
        //        //WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.JsonResponse),
        //        log.JsonRequest,
        //        log.JsonResponse,
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ExecutionDuration),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.IsSuccess ? "true" : "false"),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.InboundTraffic ? "true" : "false"),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ErrorMessage),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.Exception),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.TraceIdentifier),
        //        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(log.ServerName));
        //}

        private async Task<string> GetRequestBodyAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            try
            {
                await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
                await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
                return ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_logger.LogError(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()));
                throw;
            }
        }

        //public string GetIP(bool CheckForward,HttpContext httpContext)
        //{
        //    string ip = null;
        //    if (CheckForward)
        //    {
        //        ip = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        //    }

        //    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        //    {
        //        ip = httpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        //    }
        //    else
        //    { // Using X-Forwarded-For last address
        //        ip = ip.Split(',')
        //               .Last()
        //               .Trim();
        //    }
        //    return ip;
        //}
    }
}

Program.cs:
var providers = new LoggerProviderCollection();
var logConfig = LoggingConfiguration.GetLoggingConfiguration(builder.Configuration, providers);

FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware.ConfigLog(ref logConfig, builder.Configuration);

Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(providers: providers);

app.UseMiddleware<FraudPortalLogReqRespTraceMiddleware>();

I tried the above code to log all the requests and response of the API to a database.
I see table is getting created but no records in the table. No errors also

You've posted far too much for us to work with. Please remove all unnecessary details. Also, using an RDBMS database for storing runtime logging is not a good idea because if your database is down/unavailable you won't have any logs at all...

You're only using AuditTo - this is not how you configure a Serilog sink. Use WriteTo for that...

@Dai We have file logging and email logging (for errors/exceptions ) apart from DB as well .

@Dai I tried with WriteTo and AuditTO both ,no luck both ways

@Dai as i had already told you we have file logging as well. Request you to add the solution for this problem if you have any

As I said, you've posted far too much code for anyone to help you with (and most of it is commented out, making it a complete waste of time to review). Fix your post first.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
